# How to return whole non-latin strings matching a reduplication pattern, such as AAB or ABB

Tags: python, regex, non-latin

I am working with strings of non-latin characters.
I want to match strings with reduplication patterns, such as AAB, ABB, ABAB, etc.
I tried out the following code:

```
import re

patternAAB = re.compile(r'\b(\w)\1\w\b')
match = patternAAB.findall(rawtext)
print(match)
```

However, it reurns only the first character of the matched string.
I know this happens because of the capturing parenthesis around the first \w.

I tried to add capturing parenthesis around the whole matched block, but Python gives

```
error: cannot refer to an open group at position 7
```

I also found this method,but didn't work for me:

```
patternAAB = re.compile(r'\b(\w)\1\w\b')
match = patternAAB.search(rawtext)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

How could I match the pattern and return the whole matching string?

```
# Ex. 哈哈笑 
# string matches AAB pattern so my code returns 哈 
# but not the entire string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message:

```
error: cannot refer to an open group at position 7
```

is telling you that `\1` refers to the group with parentheses all around, because its opening parenthesis comes first. The group you want to backreference is number 2, so this code works:

```
import re

rawtext = 'abc 哈哈笑 def'

patternAAB = re.compile(r'\b((\w)\2\w)\b')
match = patternAAB.findall(rawtext)
print(match)
```

Each item in `match` has both groups:

```
[('哈哈笑', '哈')]
```

Comment: This works! Is there any doc I could use for further reference?

Comment: You can simply your regex into `\b(\w)\1\w\b` as there is no need for external parenthesis. +1 anyway

Comment: @Allan that's just what OP did in the first place, it doesn't give the full match to `findall`.

Answer (score 0):

> I also found this method, but didn't work for me:

You were close here as well. You can use `match.group(0)` to get the full match, not just a group in parentheses. So this code works:

```
import re

rawtext = 'abc 哈哈笑 def'

patternAAB = re.compile(r'\b(\w)\1\w\b')
match = patternAAB.search(rawtext)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))   # 哈哈笑
```

Comment: Why two answers? Can't you regroup it in one?

Comment: @Allan because they're different. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice